# how to lock widgets in place in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, stack, multiple-columns

I am creating a news app in flutter. I want to achieve U.I as displayed in screenshot.

[image]

in the picture attached, there is title for 1st tile which is in 3 lines, now I want this U.I for all tiles. In the second tile the title for news is one line. which is causing trouble as widgets down in column are moved up.

Here is my code.

```
Container(
                        width: 260.w,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: color.inactiveButton,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.sp))),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              controller.category.firstHeader.list[index]
                                  .thumbnail,
                              width: 260.w,
                              height: 143.h,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 260.w,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.sp),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.sp)),
                                color: color.inactiveButton,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          const Icon(
                                            Icons.remove_red_eye,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 5.w,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            '${controller.category.firstHeader.list[index].views!} Views',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                              fontSize: 11.sp,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          const FaIcon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.clock,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 5.w,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            controller.category.firstHeader
                                                .list[index].latest!,
                                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                              fontSize: 11.sp,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.h,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    controller.category.firstHeader
                                        .list[index].title,
                                    maxLines: 3,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      // color: Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.h,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.sp),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: color.highlight,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(8.sp)),
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            FaIcon(
                                              FontAwesomeIcons.faceSmile,
                                              color: color.buttonText,
                                              size: 20,
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 5.w,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              controller
                                                  .category
                                                  .firstHeader
                                                  .list[index]
                                                  .favourites!,
                                              style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                                fontSize: 11.sp,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                color: color.buttonText,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        controller.category.firstHeader
                                            .list[index].country!,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                          fontSize: 11.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` for column

```
Container(
                        width: 260.w,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: color.inactiveButton,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.sp))),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              controller.category.firstHeader.list[index]
                                  .thumbnail,
                              width: 260.w,
                              height: 143.h,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 260.w,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.sp),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.sp)),
                                color: color.inactiveButton,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
            // ----------- here ----------------------
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          const Icon(
                                            Icons.remove_red_eye,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 5.w,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            '${controller.category.firstHeader.list[index].views!} Views',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                              fontSize: 11.sp,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          const FaIcon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.clock,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            size: 20,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 5.w,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            controller.category.firstHeader
                                                .list[index].latest!,
                                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                              fontSize: 11.sp,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.h,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    controller.category.firstHeader
                                        .list[index].title,
                                    maxLines: 3,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      // color: Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.h,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.sp),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: color.highlight,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(8.sp)),
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            FaIcon(
                                              FontAwesomeIcons.faceSmile,
                                              color: color.buttonText,
                                              size: 20,
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 5.w,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              controller
                                                  .category
                                                  .firstHeader
                                                  .list[index]
                                                  .favourites!,
                                              style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                                fontSize: 11.sp,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                color: color.buttonText,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        controller.category.firstHeader
                                            .list[index].country!,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                          fontSize: 11.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
```

Comment: it should work but it did not worked.

Comment: Updated my answer (have added mainAxisSize.max also) can you try it?